# Cannot read property 'ccords' of undefined in geolocation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, geolocation

I am trying to use geolocation in my react app.

i am getting the latitude and longitude in the console, but I am getting the error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined.
```

here's my code:

```
 const [location, setLocation]= useState({
      coordinates: {lat:"", long:""}
    });
    
    const onSucces = location=>{
      setLocation({
            coordinates:{
              lat: location.coords.latitude,
              long: location.coords.longitude
          }
      })
  };
 
  useEffect(()=>{
      if (!("geolocation" in navigator)){
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported")     
        
      }
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSucces)

  }, []);
  console.log(location)


    const getTeamLeadersLocation = async () => {
      const result = await client.post('api/team/location',
      { 
        "Location":{
          "coords":{
            "latitude":location.coordinates.lat,
            "longitude":location.coordinates.long, 
          }
        } 
      } 
      )
      if(!result.ok){
        console.log(result, result.originalError, result.problem, result.status);
        return;
      }
      onSucces()
      console.log(result)
      
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getTeamLeadersLocation();
    }, []);
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getTeamLeadersLocation()` function you are calling `onSuccess` without the required `location` parameter. So it tries to access `coords` of undefined. Hence you get the error. Also, you already called your state `location` and this variable can get shadowed, so you should rename one of them. This makes it also less confusing to debug.